# Magento 2 Stock Status hide/show based on 'manage stock' status

Tags: magento2, stock-status, manage-stock

I am trying to figure a way to hide stock status/availability on product page when it is set to 'don't manage stock.'

And if it is set to 'manage stock', it should show stock status/availability on product page.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the product manage stock info using below code in phtml

```
$_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getManageStock();
```

In order to hide product stock status/availability on PDP override below file in your custom theme

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml

with below code

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<?php /* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView */?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct() ?>
<?php $_isManageStock = $_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getManageStock() ?>

<?php if($_isManageStock): ?>
    <?php if ($block->displayProductStockStatus()) :?>
        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()) :?>
            <div class="stock available" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Availability')) ?>">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php else :?>
            <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Availability')) ?>">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Check [this](https://meetanshi.com/blog/programmatically-check-whether-stock-is-managed-for-particular-product-in-magento-2/) for reference. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but that is only answering half of the question. When in stock: front should display 'in stock'.

Comment: Magento by default shows the stock availability on PDP. Also you can check the code to show stock status is there.

Comment: @RoboxFuze Is it helped you?

Comment: no. See question worded differently:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/348481/magento-2-stock-display-question

Comment: Did you checked above solution? What issue you are facing with it?

Comment: where should the code go ? In 
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml
or in my custom theme ?

Comment: It will go in your custom theme.